# What is a history.md file?

Tags: github, version-control

I see this file in many project source trees and I would like to read documentation on what how the file is meant to be used, however a Google search comes up with many "useless" results..

Can someone please point me to some real documentation?

Cheers.

Comment: There's nothing magical about `history.md`. It's a file, probably in Markdown format, containing some kind of history. Most that I've seen are used as a changelog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

History.md is ordinary file with Markdown formatting in it. The only advantage of Markdown is Github: on outputting .md-file, it renders embedded Markdown-rules in order to provide more "fancy" output, than ordinary plain-text, compary [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chriso/node.io/master/HISTORY.md)

```
### v0.4.9
    * Disabled streaming parsing as mikeal/request no longer supports options.onResponse

### v0.4.8
    * Fix the pagerank builtin
    * Fix for nested parseHtml calls

### v0.4.7
    * Break out of .each early with return false
```

and [rendered result](https://github.com/chriso/node.io/blob/master/HISTORY.md)